# Getting Input from Python Displayed Weird Characters with Arrow Keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos7

I'm running CentOS 7.x and I've experience some weird characters a user type an arrow key.  Typing any other character is fine.

I noticed this problem doesn't happen when I run in interactive shell from my virtual environment or within IDLE3.5.  It only happens when I execute the script with ./testinput.py or python3.5 testinput.py.  Any idea on how to fix this issue?

**Running the Script**

```
(virtual) $ ./testinput.py 
Type: asdf^[[D^[[D      # 2 left arrows pressed
```

**Interactive Shell**

```
(virtual) $ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 22 2016, 19:03:10) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> userinput = input ('Type: ')
Type: as|df             # Cursor moved between s and d without weird characters
```

**IDLE**

```
>>> userinput = input ('Type: ')
Type: as|df             # Cursor moved between s and d without weird characters
```

Comment: Those are the codes that the arrow key sends. Python doesn't process arrow keys by default, so you just see the characters they send.

Comment: I get it now, but how do I translate those characters into positioning the cursor to the left or right?

Comment: Use the [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) module